# Specialize a type for generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Given this definition:

```
declare function foo<T>(): { bar: T }

// <T>() => { bar: T }
type Foo = typeof foo;
```

How can one provide specialization to the generic function by its type?

What I want to achieve is to be able to do something like this:

```
// { bar: number }
type FooResult = ReturnType<Foo<number>>;
```

But TypeScript complaints that `Foo` itself is not generic - the function it types is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really support the kind of higher-order typing you'd need to get this from `ReturnType`... it's a [known design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22617#issuecomment-375123727).  So all you have available is a variety of workarounds.  Here are the ones I can think of off the top of my head:

- Do it manually. This is essentially a non-answer, but could be the best way forward since it doesn't rely on any weird type system tricks:

  ```
  type FooResult<T> = { bar: T };
  type FooResultNumber = FooResult<number>; // {bar: number}
  ```
- Pretend to actually call `foo()` and get its result.  TypeScript doesn't support [arbitrary type queries](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606), so `type FooResult = typeof foo<number>()` unfortunately does not compile.  The following code is about as close as you can get:

  ```
  const __dummy = (true as false) || foo<number>();
  type FooResultNumber = typeof __dummy; // {bar: number}
  ```

  This introduces a dummy variable in your runtime code. The `(true as false) || expression` construct uses a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to lie to the compiler.  The compiler thinks you are doing `false || expression`, the type of which will be the same as the type of `expression`.  What you are really doing at runtime is `true || expression` which short-circuits, returning `true` without ever evaluating `expression`.  This means that `foo()` never gets called at runtime despite being in the code.
- Another way to pretend to call `foo()` is with a dummy class... you will never instantiate the class but it lets the compiler reason about types:

  ```
  class __FooRunner<T> {
    result = foo<T>();
  }
  type FooResult<T> = __FooRunner<T>["result"];
  type FooResultNumber = FooResult<number>; // {bar: number}
  ```

  Again, this puts some junk in your runtime code, which may or may not be acceptable depending on your use cases.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZEwCuIA2SDeAsAFBJIAmE82IATsgGYbDwAuAlgPbBL0ccA8AFQB8ACgCUALnxIARrWmCkAXwDcxUiwCeMZADE+AJWgZsLIcKQBeGfJqKV6kkm26kBjsaimWAOQxgshA01u5GJmb8mIHBwqpIAPQJ+HbS0UE0ysRZRMSgkLAIyAAiAWBaAGq0bCCy2MiEzhRUtAxMrJzcvAIiEtJ4cgpISmoaSPBcUCxIAPozZGVaoaIsNBjIIFA8OFAQ4kgAPgc8fFEBGWLiTpo6+uHeZv4xITauEBz0s-OL8UkpQ+lgjkcnlwNA4IgkKUwOUAMLUKBbRqkZrUOg8drsLgnHqXfqDezDRxjFqIr4eQxMYDBCz4MakOgPaY2boWCTXFRjN5hTwRcwiUJzClUmkiADaACJGT4JQBdDncil8p4ZUJKplnZ5xRLJPCpJCAzLZYjEIA)