# Is it possible to set the generic type of a function without calling it in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The question is in the title. Below an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
const apiResponse = Promise.resolve({data: 1} as {data: any}); // Assume I don't know the type of data
const mapData = <T>(res: {data: T}): T => res.data;

const x = apiResponse.then(mapData<number>); // This one fails to compile
const y = apiResponse.then(mapData); // Succeeded but y is of type any
const z = apiResponse.then(_ => mapData<number>(_)); // Succeeded in some case it is inconvenient to forward parameters
```

Comment: You can only specify the type parameter of a generic function type when you call it.  `_ => f<T>(_)` is probably the best you can reasonably hope for here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specialize a type for generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142802/specialize-a-type-for-generic-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I don't see anything wrong with your "verbose" call

```
const z = apiResponse.then(_ => mapData<number>(_));
```

but if you want something else, read on:

---

Generic function types, where a single function can act as multiple types of function, only let you specify the generic type parameter when you call it.  Your `mapData` function has the following type:

```
type GenFunc = <T>(res: { data: T; }) => T
const verifyMapData: GenFunc = mapData; // okay
```

Note that `GenFunc` is not a generic type alias; it is a specific type alias which refers to a generic function type.  You can think of the type parameter `T` as "belonging to" the call signature and not to the name of the function or the name of any type alias of the function. Since it doesn't belong to the name of the function you can't write `mapData<T>` by itself and since it doesn't belong to the `GenFunc` type name you can't write `GenFunc<T>` either.

---

Compare this to the distinct but related *generic* type alias which refers to a family of *specific* function types:

```
type GenAlias<T> = (res: {data: T; }) => T
```

In this type, the generic type parameter "belongs to" the name of the type alias and not to the function type it represents.

Now it is unfortunately true that TypeScript's type system currently lacks the expressiveness necessary to take the `GenFunc` type and generate the `GenAlias<T>` type automatically.  For now at least, you need to write out `GenAlias<T>`'s type definition yourself by hand, as I just did.

---

What the compiler *can* do is recognize that a value of type `GenFunc` is assignable to a variable of type `GenAlias<T>` for any specific `T` you want, so the following compiles just fine:

```
const mapDataNumber: GenAlias<number> = mapData; // okay
```

And therefore you can get the following to compile without an extra function call, if it matters:

```
const w = apiResponse.then(mapDataNumber); // Promise<number>
```

Furthermore if you don't want to waste a line on a variable assignment you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) for a little less type safety but with absolutely no runtime effect:

```
const v = apiResponse.then(mapData as GenAlias<number>); // Promise<number>
```

Either one of those should work for you.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwJYCUCmEHgmmBeGABQCcQBbJHAOmIxABsA3NACgG8YATOKOALhgBGGAF94EGB268BcMAE9RASgDcMAPTqYAQQgQArmVwBJLuADksANZgQAdxhQAFrijyEuEADMuPOAFgAKFBIWDJEABE-fBgAHgAVAD4WWggBKT8BeOUs-ESYVKppOBUgmCCQ6BgADxjEVAwsSDQqZzQwFnCEKN5YsEMAIzRiRNUNLXinShhwXC84JHoJKBAYUDJkejQK7FhFAnr0TGwWto6unrgxzRgAZX1gYDQ0TheYAf09mGnvR3dcOTyHahGAALzqyCOTWoZxYAH08jALn4+oNhsk4Uprlp7o9nq9OO9PjBmMQBiAcDAAIRBIJuDwwADi7QAYvowMAYglkql0r4ZDB4moREpEULgVVSUgvPIALKRTJM1nszkEZG8NQ3EBWOBAwJ0-5KsDaehIOAQbkxFIYPnFLLC0V4fLi-XBXZIhW8AByaOIAmZxtN5tRZCGIxi6pK4xmOr1lVgDgOkMaJ1aLnOnrgPtDw2xRFIFBwIbDiQlsEYEIax2aafanUz4iNJrNFv6OZGeZI5EoaGL6KAA)

Comment: Thank you for this quality response. This is the 2nd time you save me theses 2 last days ;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
        const apiResponse = Promise.resolve( { data: 1, asType: ( data as any ).__proto__} as { data: any, asType: any } );
        const mapData = <T>( res: { data: any, asType: { new( ...args ): T } } ): T => {
            if ( res.data ) {
                res.data.__proto__ = res.asType;
                return res.data;
            }

            return undefined;
        }
        const y = apiResponse.then( mapData );
```

Is this what your are after?

Comment: I don't think. I absolutely don't understand what you're trying to do :D.

Comment: if in the response you pass the value and the actual type then you can infer the type in the response by assigning the types prototype object to the value object